# Ethernet speed is limited to 100mbps

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet

I am trying to setup internet connection on Intel NUC PC, but having issue with getting desired speed.

Ethernet adapter (Realtek PCIe GBE) supports gigabit speed. When connected, status shows 1000/1000 (see picture below), but internet is limited to stable 100mbps whereas available from provider speed is close to 400mbps. I can get the desired speed on all other devices (2 additional PCs and XBOX), which are connected to the same router.

[image]

Here are the steps I tried so far:

- Disabled/Enabled adapter Reinstalled adapter
- Installed latest driver
- Ran network troubleshooting
- Reset network/ip setting in CMD etc.
- Set speed in driver setting to 1.0 GB Full-duplex
- Disabled all power saving related settings
- Tried with 4 different cables (all factory made high quality cat5e/cat6 ones)
- Reset router Reset BIOS to defaults
- Checked BIOS settings to find if any limitations set. No setting like that
- Updated BIOS on the Intel NUC to latest available (0072 in my case)
- Reinstalled Windows 10

So I have no more ideas. Any help is much appreciated !

**UPDATE**

Tested with USB to Ethernet adapter same issue. Link shows 1000/1000, but internet speed is limited to 100.

Comment: Did you try a different NIC in the same machine to eliminate a NIC hardware problem? Even an external USB 3 to gigabit Ethernet dongle would be a fine test. Your current NIC could have, say, a cold solder joint (bad circuit board connection) on one of the pins of the 8P8C (RJ45) receptacle, that causes signal integrity problems on that pin. Since 100Mbit Ethernet only uses 4 of the pins but gigabit requires all 8, a signal problem on any of those 4 gigabit-specific pins will make gigabit communication impossible while 100Mbit communication will still work fine.

Comment: (Also look for bent/missing pins within the 8P8C receptacle on the NIC.)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any other NIC to try on this machine. I will try to get one from somewhere and check. Thanks for your recommendations Spiff!

Comment: Are the other PCs connected over ethernet or wifi? Have you tried using same port and cable of another working PC? Does the router support 1Gbit ethernet?

Comment: Yes, I as mentioned all other devices connected to same router are working fine. I tried cables which are used for these devices as well yes. It seems to be a hardware issue. I will make a test as Spiff suggested.

Comment: @Spiff problem does not seem to be caused by the NIC. I've tested with a brand new usb 3.0 NIC. Same issue :(

Comment: Is the device directly connected to the router you mention? Can other devices reach the desired performance when connected to the same cable in the same location?

Comment: Yes, it is. Other devices have zero issues.